# React App Using the same function in two places but the API call is different. How do I force it to use the root everytime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

So I am building an app that allows people to make posts and leave comments. I'm running into an issue where if I use the same addLikes and unLike function in two different places, the second one doesn't work.

Here is function in my action/controller file.

```
export const addLike = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.put(`api/posts/like/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_LIKES,
      payload: { id, likes: res.data },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
    });
  }
};

// Unlike

export const unLike = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.put(`api/posts/unlike/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_LIKES,
      payload: { id, likes: res.data },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
    });
  }
};
```

When I use it on the page that shows all posts from newest to oldest. The API directs to:

http://localhost:3000/api/posts/like/5ebba76c42f5fc2f98ebd94b

```
<Fragment>
      <div className='post bg-white p-1 my-1'>
        <div>
          <Link to={`/profile/${user}`}>
            <img className='round-img' src={avatar} alt='' />
            <h4>{name}</h4>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p className='my-1'>{text}</p>
          <p className='post-date'>
            Posted on <Moment format='YYYY/MM/DD'>{date}</Moment>
          </p>
          <button
            onClick={(e) => addLike(_id)}
            type='button'
            className='btn btn-light'
          >
            <i className='fas fa-thumbs-up'></i>{" "}
            <span>{likes.length > 0 && <span>{likes.length}</span>}</span>
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={(e) => unLike(_id)}
            type='button'
            className='btn btn-light'
          >
            <i className='fas fa-thumbs-down'></i>
          </button>
          <Link to={`/posts/${_id}`} className='btn btn-primary'>
            Discussion{" "}
            {comments.length > 0 && (
              <span className='comment-count'>{comments.length}</span>
            )}
          </Link>
          {!auth.loading && user === auth.user._id && (
            <button
              onClick={(e) => deletePost(_id)}
              type='button'
              className='btn btn-danger'
            >
              <i className='fas fa-times'></i>
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
```

I then am currently building fragment for showing individual posts and the API directs the to:

http://localhost:3000/posts/api/posts/like/5ebba76c42f5fc2f98ebd94b

```
      <div className='post bg-white p-1 my-1'>
        <div>
          <Link to={`/profile/${user}`}>
            <img className='round-img' src={avatar} alt='' />
            <h4>{name}</h4>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p className='my-1'>{text}</p>
          <p className='post-date'>
            Posted on <Moment format='YYYY/MM/DD'>{date}</Moment>
          </p>
          <button
            onClick={(e) => addLike(_id)}
            type='button'
            className='btn btn-light'
          >
            <i className='fas fa-thumbs-up'></i>{" "}
            <span>{likes.length > 0 && <span>{likes.length}</span>}</span>
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={(e) => unLike(_id)}
            type='button'
            className='btn btn-light'
          >
            <i className='fas fa-thumbs-down'></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
```

The two locations are:

```
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/posts' component={Posts} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/posts/:id' component={Post} />
```

How do I force the same function to use the same exact path every time instead? I'm not sure why the second situation adds the extra /posts in front of api/

Comment: I think what is happening is that when you use relative routes (like "/api/.../, axios will just prepend them to the current one. If you specify the absolute path (http://localhost:3000/api/...), it should stay consistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set and config the default base URL for Axios request.

For ex:

```
// Axios configuration
axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://example.com/";
```

Now, whenever you make your request it will automatically prefix this default baseURL to your every request.

Like: `axios.put(`api/posts/like/${id}`)` to `axios.put(`https://example.com/api/posts/like/${id}`);`

Comment: Ah thanks that makes sense. So my base routes are defined in my server.js in the root folder:

Comment: Okay, You have defined those. 

Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: I found that I was missing a "/" before the address. And adding it in to the route took it back to the root. But now I'm hitting a new issue. The like and unlike buttons are now trying to access localhost:3000 which is the website. But my my api is on 5000. This behavior doesn't show up anywhere else on anything else. I'm not sure what is causing it.

Comment: You have to proxy the request by adding a line of code in package.json file of react.

Answer (score 0):

- How come you are sending an Id on the `addLike` method. If you are creating a like you shouldn’t have its id. And the verb should be post, not put.
- the route /posts/:id shouldn’t be exact, because `:id` is dynamic.
- `<span>{likes.length > 0 && <span>{likes.length}</span>}</span>` what is the purpose behind this line ?? Shouldn’t it be:

```
....
render () {
....
const likes = likes.length;
return (
....
<span>{likes}</span>
```

- there are some gaps. What kind of Router you are using ?
- How are you setting axios ? I recommend you to use `npm i axios-es6-class`

Comment: How come you are sending an Id on the addLike method. If you are creating a like you shouldn’t have its id. And the verb should be post, not put. *For the comments, the likes are kept in an array with the user IDs of all the likers. I am adding to the array or removing when ever some one likes. So I am not really creating a like. I'm just updating who likes it*

Comment: the route /posts/:id shouldn’t be exact, because :id is dinamyc  *got it. Understood. Thank you.

Comment: <span>{likes.length > 0 && <span>{likes.length}</span>}</span> what is the purpose behind this line ?? *It's a bit messy. But the reason for that is if there are no likes I didn't want a zero to show up after the like. A number only shows up if it's greater than zero. I could probably do it more elegantly.*